# Matlab GUI waitbar

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I was writing a little script to start getting used to waitbars in MATLAB and I wanted to set the edge color of the waitbar to green and the face color to blue but it just doesn't work; I keep getting the face color in green and the edge in black.
Here's the code:

```
wb=waitbar(0,'Iterating...');
set(wb,'Name','Changing color');
wbobject=findobj(wb,'Type','Patch');
set(wbobject,'EdgeColor',[0 1 0],'FaceColor',[0 0 1]);
for i=1:1000
    waitbar(i/1000)
end
delete(wb);
```

An additional question: Would you mind explaining or referring me to a source in order to understand what is a patch in MATLAB?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `set(wb, 'Edgecolor', ...)` ? Just use the name of the object?

Comment: marcoreskt : Yes I did but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't able to see the change in `EdgeColor` because the `waitbar` figure contains a `line` object which is that outline. You'll want to find that line object and change the `Color` property of it

```
wb=waitbar(0,'Iterating...');
set(wb,'Name','Changing color');
wbobject=findobj(wb,'Type','Patch');
set(wbobject,'EdgeColor',[0 1 0],'FaceColor',[0 0 1]);

hline = findall(wb, 'type', 'line');
set(hline, 'Color', [0 1 0]);
```

[image]

Also a `patch` object is described in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html). It is essentially a filled polygon. `waitbar` uses one to represent the rectangle that indicates the progress.